# Update searchView while deleting query android

Tags: android, kotlin

I implemented a searchView with a custom searchable ListAdapter. Currently using the code I have, I can achieve most of the functionality I want. However, the query result is not updating inside the SearchView when I press backspace to delete the strings for querying. Did I implement onQueryTextChange() wrong?

MainActivity:

```
    val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager

    val searchMenuItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.search)

    val searchView = searchMenuItem.actionView as SearchView

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            (listView.adapter as MessageListAdapter).filter.filter(query)
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            (listView.adapter as MessageListAdapter).filter.filter(newText)
            return true
        }
    })
```

Comment: what is your filter method does??

Comment: the adapter takes an ArrayList of my custom objects, which contains a string, so the filter checks whether each object.string contains; if so, the object will be stored in a temp ArrayList, and when it's done, substitute the old list with the temp list

Comment: you can use filter in onQueryTextChange() remove (listView.adapter as MessageListAdapter).filter.filter(query) from onQueryTextSubmit()